# Identity Entity Framework in IdentityDbContext change all Identity class to custom class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, dbcontext

my old context is like

```
public class MYDbContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser, IdentityRole, string, IdentityUserLogin, IdentityUserRole, IdentityUserClaim> 
{
}
```

but I need some custom property in these classes changed them to

```
public class MYDbContext : IdentityDbContext<CustomUser, CustomRole, string, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim> 
{
}
```

```
public class CustomUser : IdentityUser
{       
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}

public class CustomRole : IdentityRole
{
    public int Type { get; set; }
}

public class AppUserRole : IdentityUserRole
{
    public int Type { get; set; }
}
```

and also `CustomUserLogin`, `CustomUserClaim` are the same as others without any extra property.

The problem is when i try to add new role or user I get this exception:

> System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException: 'Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors'

How can I fix it?

I tried to change my key type to Guid and it does not work, and also
I tried to change only `UserRole` class to `IdentityUserRole`, but then I got a new error CS0311 :

> Cannot be used as type parameter 'TUser' in the generic type or method 'IdentityDbContext<TUser, TRole, TKey, TUserLogin, TUserRole, TUserClaim>'. There is no implicit reference conversion

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: *See 'EntityValidationErrors'* -- Did you do that?

Comment: I am sorry and I edited @MarkSeemann

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think  error CS0311 you faced because you didn't define your user-role class to others i mean like :

```
public class CustomUser : IdentityUser<string, YourCustomUserLogin, YourCustomUserRole, YourCustomUserClaim>
{       
}

public class AppUserRole : <string, YourCustomUserRole>
{
}
```

and when you do it the Error " There is no implicit reference conversion "
should vanish.
and in my case when I define  it as i said, you inherited class  (IdentityRole) changed to a generic one look these two pictures:
[image]
[image]
or in this link look Microsoft class
[IdentityRole](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.entityframeworkcore.identityrole?view=aspnetcore-1.1)
[IdentityRole generic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.identityrole-1?view=aspnetcore-7.0)
IdentityRole generates Id inside Constructors.
that isn't Constructors for the generic one (IdentityRole)
So one of your solutions is ,create Constructors to generate Id
like :

```
 //
        // Summary:
        //     Constructor
        public IdentityRole()
        {
            base.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        }

        //
        // Summary:
        //     Constructor
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   roleName:
        public IdentityRole(string roleName)
            : this()
        {
            base.Name = roleName;
        }
```

or in some way generate your CustomClass ID

Comment: are you telling me to use <> for my Custom Class and dill it, and then set my ID when I add a new element?

Comment: yes, i faced similar problem and it work for me